# Review the functionality of the circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, relay, bjt, opto-isolator

I am designing a board for a garage door controller(to integrate it with home assistant, with an mcu esp32, wifi, and rf module). I don't have the opportunity to lab test the circuits so  im designing it with simulations only.
I would appreciate any comment on the circuit for the motor control for the close operation since it's the dangerous one since it can hurt someone.

The op-amp is used to control the BJT to open the relay for the motor of the garage door.
When CLOSE_RELAY is high from the mcu, the inverting input is at 5V. Meaning the op-amp theoretically cannot drive the BJT and drive the relay, as long as the non-inverting input isn't higher than 5V. Which i design in it to not be.

Now the OBJECTLE_SENSOR_NC is used as an "ALL GOOD" signal. Meaning when the sensor is not sensing any objectle, the OBJECTLE_SENSOR_NC should be approximate 5V and the non-inverting input at the op-amp 2.2V. Inverting input 5V, non-inverting input 2.2V the output of the op-amp is 0V. The CLOSED_DOOR_NC is used for the same purpose, but to see if the door is not in the closed position. When both "ALL GOOD" signal are present the non-inverting input is at approx. 3V. The op-amp's output still 0V.

When i drive the CLOSE_RELAY low the inverting input drops to approx. 2.6V. Just 0.4V below non-inverting so the op-amp should drive the BJT and the relay and the door would close. IF one of the "ALL GOOD" signals not present, the non-inverting will drop at 2.2V causing the op-amp to output 0V again? and the motor will stop even is the mcu for some reason tell it to move. That is the safety functionality that i though.

But it lucks a feature that it would be good to have. While the inverting is at 2.6V and non-inverting at 3V meaning that the motor is moving, when the voltage will drop below 2.6V and the motor stops, the motor should not restart again even if the voltage goes back at 3V.
The only way to restart the motor is via the mcu, meaning that the inverting should go back at 5V and then drop at 2.6V and start the motor. Any basic suggestions how to implement that, in which direction is should look?

Thanks in advance. Any comment on the circuit is appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there really a reason to have op-amp driving the transistor? Why not just connect it to the MCU directly? (through resistor)

Comment: @floppydisk i want to be able to stop the motor without the need of the mcu to be working. In case of the mcu being “frozen”.

Comment: To get the functionality you want, you really need a flip flop or latch that can be set by the MCU to start the closing process and reset by your limit switch inputs to stop the motor. Using an op-amp in this way rather than logic devices is muddled and bizarre.